# Gmail API for managing multiple signatures

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

Google recently released an update to Gmail to bring support for multiple signatures. Ref: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8395.

I do not see anything in the API documentation at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference that talks about how to manage those multiple signatures. How can I:

- create a new signature
- update a specific existing signature
- associate a signature to an email address - both the "for new emails use" and "on reply/forward use"

Is there any documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

### It is a bit hidden, the signature(s) need to be created with [Users.settings.sendAs: create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/create) or `update`

As specified for the [resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs#resource), `signature` is one of the parameters that can be modified and you do not need to create a new alias, but can also apply this method to your primaary email:

> Settings associated with a send-as alias, which can be either the
>   primary login address associated with the account or a custom "from"
>   address.

**Important: Access restricted to service accounts that have been delegated**

Sample with Apps Script:

```
function createAlias() {
  var alias = 'your primary email';
  var signature = 'Your signature';

  var service = getOAuthService();
  service.reset();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {

    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/settings/sendAs'
    var headers ={
      "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken(),
      "Accept":"application/json", 
      "Content-Type":"application/json",
    };

    var resource ={
      sendAsEmail: alias,
      signature: signature,

    };

    var options = {
      'headers': headers,
      'method': 'POST',
      'payload':JSON.stringify(resource),
      'muteHttpExceptions': true
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());

  }
}
```

Necessary scope:
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing`

Comment: This works well for managing send as signatures, but question is, how you manage (get, set) gmail's multiple signatures (which are new thing and are different from send as signatures)

Comment: Yes -- this works for the old way but doesn't accommodate the multiple signature feature that they recently rolled out for Gmail.

Comment: As you say, the multiple signature feature just rolled out, so it has not been implemented in the API yet. You can always file a feature request to speed things up. Sorry if my solution for "classic signatures" has not been helpful for you.

Comment: Hi there any news about multiple signatures? thanks