# Adding sendAsMail Alias in GMail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I've been trying to add another sendasmail alias from sometimes visa app scripts but the endpoint doesn't seem to work or I'm not sure if that's the intended behavior of it.

This is the endpoint `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/%s/settings/sendAs/%s',getEmail, "007@alias.domain.com"` that I'm using.

Here's the AppScipt Code along with payload which I'm trying to use.

```
            var service = getOAuthService(getEmail);
            var sendAPIUrl = Utilities.formatString('https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/%s/settings/sendAs/%s',getEmail, "007@alias.domain.com");
console.log(sendAPIUrl);
            var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sendAPIUrl, {
              method: "PUT",
              muteHttpExceptions: true,
              contentType: "application/json",
              headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
              },
              payload: JSON.stringify({
                 "sendAsEmail": "007@alias.domain.com",
                  "isDefault": true,
                  "replyToAddress": "007@alias.domain.com",
                  "treatAsAlias": true
              })

            });
```

In getEmail, it holds the primary email Address of user and getOauthService is basically another function for user impersonation as for changing senAsEmail;s only service accounts will work.

I tried sending a POST request to create one, but failed with an error code while alias pattern is allowed in domain alias list and alias is available.

Here's the code for POST

```
    var service = getOAuthService(getEmail);
                var sendAPIUrl = 
Utilities.formatString('https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/%s/settings/sendAs',getEmail);
    console.log(sendAPIUrl);
                var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sendAPIUrl, {
                  method: "POST",
                  muteHttpExceptions: true,
                  contentType: "application/json",
                  headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
                  },
                  payload: JSON.stringify({
                     "sendAsEmail": "007@alias.domain.com",
                  })
                });
                console.log(response.getContentText())
```

and this is the error that I got.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "sendAsEmail is not a valid user or group",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "sendAsEmail is not a valid user or group",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalidArgument"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Comment: The email that you select must be one of the emails that is already setup in your gmail.  So it should be one of the emails you will see at GmailApp.getAliases()

Comment: @Cooper So basically we can just set an existing alias as the default address, we can't add one alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You need to create an alias instead of updating it

- When you make a `PUT` request to the [https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/settings/sendAs/{sendAsEmail}](https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/%7BuserId%7D/settings/sendAs/%7BsendAsEmail%7D) endpoint, you can [update](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/update) an already existing alias
- Thereby, you need to specify the new `{ "sendAsEmail": "" }` in the request body and the old `sendAs` in the request URL
- If instead you want to [create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/create) a new, non-existing alias, you need to make a `POST` request to the [https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/settings/sendAs](https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/%7BuserId%7D/settings/sendAs) endpoint

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61921754/gmail-api-for-managing-multiple-signatures/61934046#61934046).

Comment: just updated the question as can't add code here. I tried creating it but got an error straight away. I'm looking to create a non-existing alias thanks for taking the question in right direction :).

Comment: The sendAs needs to be a valid, existing user of your domain.